# Fixed number of rows per page in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently creating an excel file which has a report sheet.
This sheet is filled-in with data by VBA script.
Also I've created a button for export report to PDF.

Everything works fine, until this file is opened on another PC with different screen resolution.
Rows height, and actual font size is changed which leads to mess in PDF pages, some of them have half of tables an so on.

Is there any way to force Excel not to change rows height or, probably another way to fix rows number per page?

I'm using Excel for Office 365.

Thanks!

Update
Here comes a script I use for PDF generation

```
Public Sub SaveResultsToPDF()
    Dim wsA As Worksheet
    Dim wbA As Workbook
    Dim strTime As String
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPathFile As String
    Dim myFile As Variant
    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsA = ActiveSheet
    strTime = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")

    'get active workbook folder, if saved
    strPath = wbA.Path
    If strPath = "" Then
        strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
    End If
    strPath = strPath & "\"

    'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
    strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
    strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

    'create default name for savng file
    strFile = strName & "_" & strTime & ".pdf"
    strPathFile = strPath & strFile

    'user can enter name and select folder for file
    myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
        (InitialFileName:=strPathFile, _
            FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
            Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

    Dim bottom As Integer: bottom = FindEndOfPrintArea + 30

    With wsA.PageSetup
        .printArea = "A1:R" & bottom
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .LeftMargin = 42
        .RightMargin = 42
        .TopMargin = 42
        .BottomMargin = 42
    End With

    'export to PDF if a folder was selected
    If myFile <> "False" Then
        wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=myFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you configure the page setup in the report?

Comment: Yep, I configure it in vba:  
    With wsA.PageSetup 
        .printArea = "A1:R" & bottom


        .Orientation = xlPortrait


        .LeftMargin = 42


        .RightMargin = 42


        .TopMargin = 42


        .BottomMargin = 42


    End With

Comment: Please edit your question and copy your code there.

Comment: How do you export it to pdf? Don't you print it to pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented solution based on dynamically calculated zoom factor.
Keep in mind that here we have two different DPIs: screen and print(pdf).
Once Windows DPI scaling change screen DPI, print DPI remains the same.

Here comes a code:

```
Function CalculateZoomFactor() As Long
Dim aWS As Worksheet
Set aWS = Sheets(2)

Dim pane
Set pane = Application.ActiveWindow.ActivePane

'Original settings on which page setup was configured
Dim originalPointsH As Long: originalPointsH = 30
Dim originalH As Long: originalH = 40 ' 40px original results row height
Dim originalPdfDPI As Long: originalPdfDPI = 600
Dim originalScreenDPI As Long

'Current settings which may influent on pagesetup
Dim currentH As Long
Dim currentPdfDPI As Long: currentPdfDPI = aWS.PageSetup.PrintQuality(1)  ' default PDF printer DPI
Dim currentScreenDPI As Long

currentH = pane.PointsToScreenPixelsY(aWS.Range("A2").Height) - pane.PointsToScreenPixelsY(0)

currentScreenDPI = currentH / (originalPointsH / Application.InchesToPoints(1))
originalScreenDPI = originalH / (originalPointsH / Application.InchesToPoints(1))

CalculateZoomFactor = originalPdfDPI * 100 / (currentPdfDPI - originalScreenDPI + currentScreenDPI)
```

End Function